# How to set customized color for a Text component with styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I want to set a Text component's color dynamically. When there is a disable condition then change to another color.

```
import React from "react";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

type TextType = {
  text: string;
  disable: string;
};

export const Text: React.FC<TextType> = ({ text, disable }) => {
  return <TextStyle disable>{text}</TextStyle>;
};

const TextStyle = styled.span`
  ${({ theme }) => css`
    color: ${(props) =>
      props.disable ? theme.color.text : theme.color.disable};
  `}
`;
```

The `props.disable` got error

```
Property 'disable' does not exist on type 'ThemeProps<DefaultTheme>'. [2339]
```

The `theme` is

```
export const theme = {
  color: {
    text: black,
    disable: blue,
  },
};
```

I want to use it as

```
<Text disable text={text} />
```

Or

```
<Text text={text} disable={disable} />
```

Is it necessary to define a `disable` property in theme const?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it is because the first argument in your styled component Text is 'theme', while it should be props. so in your case there is a confusion between theme and props.
try this see if it works :

```js
import React from "react";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

type TextType = {
  text: string;
  disable: string;
};

export const Text: React.FC<TextType> = ({ text, disable }) => {
  return <TextStyle disable={disable} >{text}</TextStyle>;
};

const TextStyle = styled.span`
  ${(props) => css`
    color: ${ props.disable ? props.theme.color.text : props.theme.color.disable};
  `}
`;
```

Also, the disable prop that you are passing in your component is not the same as the disable property in your theme. If you do not wish to have a different name for each as to avoid confusion, may be you should at least say that the disable you are passing into your component as a prop is of type boolean, like so :

```js
type TextType = {
  text: string;
  disable: boolean;
};
```

Comment: In this way, the `return <TextStyle disable={disable} >{text}</TextStyle>;` got `No overload matches this call.` And `color: ${props.disable` in `styled.span` got `Property 'disable' does not exist on type`. It doesn't work neither using `disable: string` nor `disable: boolean`.